# Smoothing jagged edges without anti-aliasing - Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, windows-store-apps, antialiasing

Is there a way to smooth out jagged edges of a cube without applying anti-aliasing? This is what my cube currently looks like.

[image]

I do not want to use anti-aliasing because it does not work when I export the game to Windows Store.

Comment: No other way dude, as Anti-Aliasing is the only technology to smooth out edges. If there is, then it is a new break through Technology. FYI, there are a lot of Anti-Aliasing methods but all of them comes down to one category = Anti-Aliasing. Now if you're looking for a light weight Anti alias, just check the other types Avoid MSAA as much as possible FXAA is the standard one.

Comment: uh well that's gona be a problem for me then, it works fine on android, my problem is windows store.. Ok thanks, ill look into FXAA

Comment: Yes, no other way. But once I was doing a project like this, I found out that a constantly shaking the camera to a very tiny amount gives the impression of smoothing the edges. I went with it. But obviously it depends on your setup. May not work for you.

Comment: @ImtiajAhmed can you explain a bit? shaking the camera how?

Comment: I mean, transforming the camera position at a very little amount back and forth in very little time. Though the transformation I have done on only one axis, you can try what seems to be OK for you.

Comment: hmm I don't think that would work for me.. thanks though